# Find minimum value with subquery in HAVING clause

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I need to answer the question:

> "In a system with roles and permissions, what is the lowest ranking role that has a given permission?"

I'm trying to use a subquery in the HAVING clause but any other way to answer the question is fine.

There are three tables involved: `permissions`, `roles`, and `permission_roles`. A simplified structure is below.

**PERMISSIONS**

| `id` | `permission_name` |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | View Customer |
| 2 | Edit Customer |
| 3 | Create Customer |

**ROLES**

| `id` | `role_name` | `role_level` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | agent | 25 |
| 102 | manager | 50 |
| 103 | executive | 75 |

**PERMISSION_ROLE**

| `id` | `role_id` | `permission_id` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 101 | 1 |
| 1002 | 102 | 1 |
| 1003 | 102 | 2 |
| 1004 | 103 | 1 |
| 1005 | 103 | 2 |
| 1006 | 103 | 3 |

This is the result I am trying to produce, given the data above:

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

| `Permission ID` | `Permission` | `Role Name` | `Lowest Role Level` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | View Customer | agent | 25 |
| 2 | Edit Customer | manager | 50 |
| 3 | Create Customer | executive | 75 |

The query below gives me the level for each role, but I want to list only the role(ss) with the lowest `role_level` - 1 result for each permission, showing the role(s) with the lowest `role_level` value for that permission. I'm trying to use the HAVING clause without success. Any help appreciated.

```
SELECT
    `permissions`.`id` `Permissions ID`,
    `permissions`.`permission_name` `Permission`,
    `roles`.`role_name` `Role`,
    `roles`.`role_level` `Role Level`
FROM
    `permissions`
    LEFT JOIN `permission_role` ON `permissions`.`id` = `permission_role`.`permission_id`
    LEFT JOIN `roles` ON `roles`.`id` = `permission_role`.`role_id`
WHERE
    GROUP BY 
        `permissions`.`id`
ORDER BY `permissions`.`id` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use subquery to get min `role_id` each `permission_id` from `permission_role` table, then do `JOIN`

```
SELECT
  p.id PermissionsID,
  p.permission_name Permission,
  r.role_name Role,
  r.role_level RoleLevel
FROM
 (
     SELECT permission_id,min(role_id) role_id
     FROM permission_role
     GROUP BY permission_id
) pr
JOIN permissions p ON p.id = pr.permission_id
JOIN roles r ON r.id = pr.role_id
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bfd2b9cfab6840862f693ebc70dd0f82)